# NLP: Mapping Penn treebank and Brown corpus, to Universal PoS Tags

Tags: deep-learning, classification, nlp

I am experimenting with NLP and PoS tagging. I wish to build a large corpus, composed of Penn Treebank and Brown corpus, and possibly even more. Unfortunately, their PoS tags are not compatible.

Is there a way to map their tags to universal tagging? (Or any other tagging?)

Answer (score 1):

NLTK contains options for retrieving brown, treebank corpora with universal tags, instead of their own tagging schemes.

```
nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_words(tagset='universal')
```

instead of:

```
nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_words()
```

Similarly:

```
nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_words(tagset='universal')
nltk.corpus.nps_chat.tagged_words(tagset='universal')
nltk.corpus.conll2000.tagged_words(tagset='universal')
```

As far as I am aware, none of the other tagged corpora support the universal tagset option.